# How to create Eclipse EFS resources on the fly in a content provider?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, android-contentprovider, archive

I like to write a plugin for Eclipse, which allows to work with archive files as with normal file directories. For instance, if there is a zip file inside a project, the user should be able to view the contents of the zip file just by opening the zip folder. The user should be able e.g., to read text files in that archive.

I already created an EFS wrapper arround a particular archive format. Also, I created a new content-type for this archive format. I have a navigatorContent which is triggered on the content-type. In the content provider, currently I provide objects of type IFileStore. AFAIK there isn't any nice label provider shipped with eclipse for this types so I have to implement it on my own (there is one which is declared as private). However, this seems to be rather huge code duplication effort. What I therefore like to do is not to return IFileStore but IFile or IFolder instead so that the normal project explorer content provider can do its job. Is it possible at all to do something like this? If so, how can this practical be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Call IFolder.createLink() to create a new resource referencing a folder on your custom filesystem.

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_efs_resources.htm

This will create a new folder in your project, containing all files from ZIP archive. The problem, however is, that you will need to put it into an existing container, polluting resource tree.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [`ILabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ILabelProvider.html) is not a huge effort at all, especially when compared to `IFile` or `IFolder`. If you extend [`BaseLabelprobivider`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/BaseLabelProvider.html) you only need to implement 2 methods: `getText()` and `getImage()`.